# java: how to make sure customer can't book two session got same time

Tags: java, mysql

I got a sql database contain name of sessions and their times
I retrieved session name in j-list and retrieve their times in j-text field

I want someone to help me with the logic
if two sessions at same time you can't book both

Comment: `if (sessionA.Time == sessionB.Time) return false;`?  You haven't given us much to go on here.  What have you tried and how is that attempt not working?  We can't see your code or your database, so we can't directly fix it for you.

Comment: i tried to import sessions time to 2  text fields and then compare them if both are equal user who made log in can't book the other session but obviously it won't happen if i add more sessions to sessions table

Comment: Or simply check if sesssionA time == time of any session..b,c,d..return false.

Comment: u mean select all time from sessions then compare them with each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the session time and name as unique in your table, then MySQL will take care of not creating two records with the same time.

like that:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX session_index ON your_table (session_time, session_name);
```

In your code you will need to handle the exception thrown by MySQL in case of duplicate entry.

Comment: no sir i want to be able to have many sessions at same time but same customer can book only one of them

Comment: ok, so make the combination unique. I edited my answer according to you comment.

Comment: this way i can't put 2 sessions in sessions table with same time value which i don't want to do

Comment: No, it means that two records with the same name and time are disallowed. But two records with the same time value are allowed.

Comment: ok please bear with me now how can i make tables of the 2 sessions which have the same time 
can't contain same customer name

Comment: just as I wrote above, look at the syntax of create unique index with two columns.